# 2 column layout of divs with varying heights where vertical spacing is always the same?

Tags: css

Can the layout in the image below be achieved with CSS? I have a number of divs with dynamic content and therefore varying heights.

I need a 2 column layout. I need the vertical space between the divs to always be equal.

[image]

Ive marked the divs from 1 to 5 above with the order that I would like them to appear in the HTML if possible. However the order below would be my second choice.

[image]

Comment: Ive tried inline-block and flex-flow: row wrap. Neither achieve what I need. Ill post back in a little while with an image of the layout they provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/7n2YH/1/)**

css

```
body {
    font: 1em/1.67 'Open Sans', Arial, Sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background: #e9e9e9;
}


.container {
    margin: 1.5em;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
    column-gap: 1.5em;
    font-size: .85em;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
}

.panel {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0 #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}
.panel1, .panel3  {
    background: #aaa;
    height: 100px;
}
.panel2, .panel4, .panel6  {
    background: #aaa;
    height: 200px;
}
.panel5, .panel7  {
    background: #aaa;
    height: 150px;
}
```

html

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="panel panel1">1</div>
   <div class="panel panel2">2</div>
   <div class="panel panel3">3</div>
   <div class="panel panel4">4</div>
   <div class="panel panel5">5</div>
   <div class="panel panel6">6</div>
   <div class="panel panel7">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 cannot be achieved with vanilla CSS, you wil neeed to use a library such as [**Masonry**](http://masonry.desandro.com), or [**Isotope**](http://isotope.metafizzy.co)

The second can be achieved using CSS columns (with the additional benefit of being responsive, resize the viewing area to see), e.g:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Va95q/1/)

HTML

```
<div class='cols'>
    <div class='item'>item 1</div>
    <div class='item'>item 2</div>
    <div class='item'>item 3</div>
    <div class='item'>item 4</div>
    <div class='item'>item 5</div>
    <div class='item'>item 6</div>
    <div class='item'>item 7</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.cols {
    -webkit-column-width: 20em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 2em;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-width: 20em;
    -moz-column-gap: 2em;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -ms-column-width: 20em;
    -ms-column-gap: 2em;
    -ms-column-count: 2;
    column-width: 20em;
    column-gap: 2em;
    column-count: 2;
}
.item {
    break-inside: avoid-column;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.item:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```